# Legend for overlapping line plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am overlapping two line plots in the same graph. While everything looks fine the legend for first line plot is missing.

Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)


total_colorectal <- data.frame(
  Year= c(2014:2018),
  Numbers=c(213,198,227,238,253)
)


total_colorectal_by_gender <- data.frame(
  Gender = c("M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F"),
  Year= c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018,2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018),
  Numbers = c(118, 127, 128,132,139,95,71,99,106,114)
)



ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = total_colorectal, aes(x = Year, y = Numbers)) +
  geom_line(data = total_colorectal_by_gender, aes(x = Year, y = Numbers, color=Gender)) + theme_bw()
```

The graph shows the legend for second line plot but the legend of first is missing. I don't want to have a legend title, only three labels as Both, M and F respectively.

I tried removing legend title by adding `theme(legend.title = element_blank())` at the end of code. That indeed removed the title but still the label for first line plot was missing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify color in aes with the first geom_line() call. One way is to bind the two data.frames and make the plot:

```
total_colorectal %>% 
mutate(Gender="Both") %>% 
bind_rows(total_colorectal_by_gender) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Numbers, col=Gender)) + 
geom_line() + 
scale_color_manual(name="",values=c("#827397","#ffb6b6","#679b9b"))
```

[image]